# RavenDB Server Mode Performance

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm trying to get data from my RavenDB database. I created  a static index and tried to do my request through my webservice using the recommended DLL Raven.Client.Lightweight. This step takes 3 seconds to get data.

But if i do the same query through the RavenDB interface, I get the data in 10 ms (see fewer).

Have you any idea why the execution time is slow in server mode ?

Thanks!

EDIT : Here some code :
I initialize my document in the global.asax of my webservice :

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static DocumentStore store;
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        store = new DocumentStore { Url = Settings.Default.Url };
        store.Initialize();
        store.Conventions.AllowQueriesOnId = true;
    }
}
```

My Request :
public static class ServiceBusiness
    {
        private static IDocumentSession Session = GetSession("programs");

```
    public void MyTestMethod (string MyParamId, string PageNume, string  NbItems)
    {
        List<Content> contents = new List<Content>();
        using (var Session = Global.store.OpenSession("MyDb"))
            {
                contents = Session.Query<Content>("Test")
                                .Where(x => x.Programs.Any(y => y.Products.Any(z => z.Values.Any(w => w.Id == MyParamId))))
                                .Skip((int.Parse(PageNum) - 1) * int.Parse(NbItems))
                                .Take(int.Parse(NbItems))
                                .ToList();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running these tests 10 or more times in succession and taking the average? If not, it's possible that the delay you're seeing is .NET loading the DLL (and others) and so is not a good comparison.

Comment: I tried now to do 2 differents test :

Comment: How are you initializing the DocumentStore in your webservice? Some code would help identifying what might be wrong.

Comment: I tried now to do 2 different tests. The first call the method each time with different values for the indexed field : the result is always the same in the console of RavenDB or in the debug mode the execution is always smaller than 1 second and the execution time of the service takes more time. The second test : i called the same query x times, the first call is long but the others are better.

Comment: What is the size of the documents that you are getting back? Can you show the fiddler output of talking to RavenDB?

Comment: Hi, the size of the responses depends on the request. 
Here an example of a request where the size of the request is equal to 100031 bytes. (Sometimes the size is 4x bigger).
Execution time in the RavenDB Console : 0:00:02.093ms
Execution time in Fiddler : 0:00:02.148
Execution time in c# service : 0:00:02.6020410

Comment: And 
Here the timing info throw Fiddler :
ClientConnected: 10:40:54.689
ClientBeginRequest: 10:40:54.694
GotRequestHeaders: 10:40:54.694
ClientDoneRequest: 10:40:54.694
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup:   0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 10:36:52.196
FiddlerBeginRequest: 10:40:54.697
ServerGotRequest: 10:40:54.698
ServerBeginResponse: 10:40:54.843
GotResponseHeaders: 10:40:54.843
ServerDoneResponse: 10:40:56.841
ClientBeginResponse: 10:40:56.842
ClientDoneResponse: 10:40:56.843

Comment: I did the same request on the same server where RavenDb is installed and the execution times are faster : the time between the step GotResponseHeaders:and ServerDoneResponse is immediately. Is something to modify in the settings of RavenDB ?

Comment: Something is strange in the response of RavenDB, the content type seen in Fidder is equal to RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
~???????~: 388 020
~headers~: 235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the high response time is due to the size of packets sent in the network (limited to 1514 bytes). We spend many time to assemble all the packets.